# Confusion about faithful homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $Q=\oplus_{u \in V} Ru$ be a free left $R$-module on a set $V$. Let also consider $End(Q)$, my first confusion is about how we can see $End(Q)$ as a ring, and then how can we check that such this homomorphism $R \to End(Q)$ is faithful?

Comment: $\operatorname{End}(Q)$ is a ring under pointwise addition and with composition as multiplication. Presumably the morphism $R \to \operatorname{End}(Q)$ maps $r$ to left multiplication by $r$ on every factor? If so, evaluate the induced endomorphism on $(1,0, 0, \ldots)$.